# For $x^a = e^2x$. Determine the solutions as a power of$ e$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, roots

For $x^a = e^2x$. Determine the solutions as a power of $e$

One obvious solution is $0$ but I fail to find the second solution.

$x^a - e^2x = 0$

$x(x^{a-1} - e^2) = 0$

I am not sure how to find the other solution please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solution comes from

$$x^{a-1}=e^2$$ and taking the power $1/(a-1)$,

$$x=e^{2/(a-1)}.$$

Comment: I came here for the solution, but rather I found out that I am an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: @Nhoj_Gonk: both for the price of one, you lucky guy !

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$=$e^k$
Then, $$\therefore e^{ka}=e^{k+2}$$$$\Rightarrow ka=k+2$$$$\Rightarrow k= \frac{2}{a-1}$$$$\therefore x=e^{\frac {2}{a-1}}$$

Comment: MrHolmes thanks for the answer, I want to know why you choose $x = e^k$?

Comment: Because the question says 'the solutions as power of $e$'

Comment: Right I see, thank you!